# My Example got approved, but never got the reputation for it?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-examples

My topic and example just got approved in Documentation. But I did not gain any reputation for the same. Why did this happen?

My example is this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jboss/6853/connecting-to-mysql-database-for-jboss-as-7/23241/setting-up-mysql-for-jboss-as-7#t=201609190510021191442

Comment: IIRC creating a new example is not considered an "edit" but an addition. You'll only get rep for that if an upvoted answer cites it and/or it gets upvoted by someone other then yourself.

Comment: @Magisch  It usually gets you a +2 if approved. I didn't get that.

Comment: Happened to me as well, created a topic, reviewed and accepted, an no +2   http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/phpunit/6525/assertions/23271/assert-an-exception-is-thrown#t=201609191650009176438

Comment: @Katie Yeah, it's weird!

Comment: Happened to me again...I feel like the Charlie Brown of Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I go to your reputation tab, I see this:

[image: Rep change on Sept. 19]

The +2 comes from the [approved change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/97011) to the topic and the +5 comes from an upvote to [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jboss/6853/connecting-to-mysql-database-for-jboss-as-7/23241/setting-up-mysql-for-jboss-as-7#t=201610111745100884393). So I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I got for this one. But not for the Scala articles I wrote.

Comment: Could you provide a link?

Comment: You are right, my bad. I did not get that reputation at that time. But I guess it was added later.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Is there any point in doing a edit for very old post specially when documentation is shutdown.... I asked because one day I got lot of donvotes writing a answer for a question. someone comments that he downvote because there is no point in getting this post to home page again